# Running child process with regex return is not recognized error on windows

Tags: javascript, node.js, regex, windows, makefile

I use the following code to get `Make` file targets

```
const command = `make -qp | awk -F':' '/^[a-zA-Z0-9][^$#\\/t=]*:([^=]|$)/ {split($1,A,/ /);for(i in A)print A[i]}'`;

cp.exec(command, options, (error, stdout, stderr) => {
  if (error) {
    reject({ error, stdout, stderr });
  }
});
```

When using it via code im getting an error (Windows) :

```
"'$)' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
"
```

However, if I run the exact command on the **terminal, it works**! What could be the problem?

Btw, on MacOS the code is working, is there any workaround? What can be missing the regular expression?

I've tried also with [shelljs](https://github.com/shelljs/shelljs) and got the exact same error, maybe I miss some escape character?

I use NodeJS [`child_process`](https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html#child_process_class_childprocess).

How I can make it work?

If there is other way to get makefile target I can try?

Comment: It looks pretty clearly like whatever is running your command is running it inside a Windows command.com, which fails because it's not a Windows batch file it's a POSIX shell scxript file; when you run it from the terminal it's running inside a POSIX shell which is what you want.

Comment: @MadScientist - thank you! , how you suggest me to overcome this issue ?

Comment: I have no idea, I never use Windows :)  Please add tags to your question about the platform and tools you're using (is the above javascript?  I have no idea) and maybe someone will be able to help.

Comment: @MadScientist - do you think that it's related to windows? does the node, https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html#child_process_class_childprocess should cover all the platforms ?

Comment: Certainly related to windows.  Yes, the `exec` function is part of js and is available on all systems.  But what the `exec` function does is run some other program, and the other program it runs could be different depending on the operating system.  On windows, it's apparently running the windows command.com.  On a POSIX system like GNU/Linux or MacOS it will run a POSIX-based shell like bash.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an issue regarding Windows pipe `|` escaping. You have use double quotes instead of single quotes.

#### Using double quotes instead of single quotes:

```
const command = `make -qp | awk -F":" "/^[a-zA-Z0-9][^$#\\/t=]*:([^=]|$)/ {split($1,A,/ /);for(i in A)print A[i]}"`;
```